# Encontrar valores repetidos em uma lista e inserir outro valor em seu lugar com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho uma lista que contém outras listas com dados referentes a nome, idade e altura de várias pessoas:

```
pessoas = [['PAULO', 75, 1.74], ['ANDRE', 15, 1.87], ['PEDRO', 26, 1.46], ['JULIO', 75, 1.78], ['PAULO', 84, 1.88], ['JOÃO', 34, 1.56], ['SERGIO', 88, 1.74]]
```

Feito isso, eu criei um `for` para encontrar pessoas com nomes repetidos. **Caso encontre um nome igual, ele compara a idade. Se essa pessoa com o mesmo nome for mais velha, ele substitui a idade e a altura dessa pessoa com o mesmo nome, criando assim uma nova lista (l).** Ou seja, eu nao quero nomes repetidos na lista. Caso haja, ele deixa na nova lista a pessoa que for mais velha, com sua respectiva idade.

Esse foi meu código:

```
l = []
for i in pessoas:
    if pessoas[i][0] not in l: #SE NÃO TIVER NENHUMA PESSOA COM ESSE NOME, É INSERIDO OS DADOS DA PRIMEIRA PESSOA
        l.append(i)
    else:
        idadeindex = l.index(pessoas[i][0]) #SE JÁ TIVER ESSE NOME, Ó CÓDIGO PROCURA O INDEX DO NOME QUE JA ESTA DENTRO DA LISTA
        if l[idadeindex][1] < pessoas[i][1]: #SE A IDADE DE QUEM ESTA DENTRO DA LISTA FOR MENOR DA PESSOA QUE ESTÁ FORA
            l[idadeindex][1] = pessoas[i][1] #POR FIM, ELE SUBSTITUI A IDADE E A ALTURA, MATENDO O NOME
            l[idadeindex][2] = pessoas[i][2]
print(l)
```

Ele volta esse erro:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Sou novato em Python e não consigo fazer meu código funcionar. Alguém consegue pensar em uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso?

Comment: Jonatas, seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Não use cumprimentos e/ou saudações, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro está sendo gerado porque você está percorrendo cada lista da sua lista de listas e tentando usá-las como um índice, que deve ser um número inteiro.

O que você certamente queria fazer é:

```
for i in range(len(pessoas)):
    # Código...
```

Para verificar se os nomes já existem na lista, o ideal seria usar um dicionário. Dessa forma, não seria mais necessário pesquisar pelo índice, mas sim pelo nome. Veja o código abaixo:

```
pessoas_filtradas = {}

for pessoa in pessoas:
    if not pessoa[0] in pessoas_filtradas:
        # Aqui ele adiciona apenas [altura, peso] porque o
        # nome já é registrado como chave.
        pessoas_filtradas[pessoa[0]] = pessoa[1:]
    else:
        if pessoas_filtradas[pessoa[0]][0] < pessoa[1]:
            pessoas_filtradas[pessoa[0]] = pessoa[1:]
```

Comment: Complementando... Se quiser a resposta em lista como a original, faça `nova_lista = [[k]+v for k, v in pessoas_filtradas.items()]`